# How to get local times for sunrises, sunsets and the current local time with openweathermap API in React JS

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap

I'm creating a react weather app and i'm using the OneCall API from openweathermap. The API provides me with Unix timestamps, which i need to format in order to display the correct times, for that i'm using moment js but i can't figure out how to correctly use the `dt`, `sunrise`, `sunset` and `timezone_offset` properties to calculate the times.

These are the properties i get from the fetch call:

```
dt: 1680252675,
timezone_offset: 7200,
sunrise: 1680237838,
sunset: 1680284223
```

I have a card component in my sidebar where the time and other information is displayed, the card gets the data from the api call passed as a prop.
I tried dividing the `timezone_offset` by 3600 and then multiplying it with the `dt`.
Time gets displayed in the correct format but its the incorrect time.:

```
const WeatherCard = ({item}) => {

  return (
    <div className="city-time">
          <h1 className="text-xl">{item.timezone}</h1>
          <p className="text-sm">{moment((item.timezone_offset / 3600) * item.current.dt).format("HH:mm")}</p>
     </div>
  );
}

export default WeatherCard
```

My `SetRise` component receives a prop called `times`, which is an object with a `sunrise, sunset and offset` property, here i tried the same approach as in my `WeatherCard` component:

```
const SetRise = ({times}) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col items-start justify-between">
      <p className="text-2xl">{moment((times.offset / 3600) * times.sunrise).format("hh:MM")}</p>
      <p className="text-2xl">{moment((times.offset / 3600) * times.sunset).format("hh:MM")}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SetRise
```